# Excel - to format the data in a more readable way

Tags: excel

[image: cleaning up a table]

Is it possible to get the above table in a format such as the table below, in a much easier manner without having to do a brute force approach of creating 9 columns for the LTV band and assigning it a PD value in the table?

Comment: Lookup the use of a pivot table.

Comment: Why do you have 2 of several month/year combinations? can we consolidate those onto one row or do they have to be separate?

Comment: That is a much better idea. Thank you. I will consolidate the month and year.

Answer (score 3):

Excel... Insert Pivot table
Select range and fill in as layed out in image below.

[image]

you can hide grand totals if you want by right clicking on the pivot table and selecting Pivot table options then the totals & filters

There are many other features as well but this gives you the general idea.

As to missing LTV values, you just need blank rows for each value so the chart pivots on all the data.

Comment: This was very helpful. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

OK, Here's an idea

You can do what you want using a complicated index formula that checks the Year and the Month and other number but it's quite complicated, so.

Use a formula to create an ID column to the left of your data and you can use a fairly simple vlookup to extract the data.

The ID will be the YEAR + MONTH + B + I.TV number.  On my sheet the formula is.

```
=C2&D2&"B"&E2
```

Next create your new table by listing the Years and Months and entering in the headings B1 to B9.  Then put your vlookup in the first cell under B1.

```
=iferror(vlookup($A12&$B12&C$11,$B$2:$F$9,5,false),"")
```

It's not too complicated, `$A12&$B12&C$11` builds the ID we want to search for using the Year, Month and Heading B1 cells.  Pay attention to the way the cell references are locked as that allows you to autofill across and down while still referencing the headings etc.  `$B$2:$F$9` is the range you want to use for the vlookup and `5` is the column with the data you want to return.

Have a look at my example below.

[image: Screenshot]